# Apex Trigger Creating Event on Account- Won't show in Open Activities

Tags: apex, trigger, account, event

I've created an Apex trigger on a custom object that creates an event for an account. The trigger works, and I have the data, but I can't get it to show up under Accounts=> Choose Account=> Open Activities.

In an attempt to figure it out, I manually created a new event with the same start and end date/times in the Open Activities section under the account by clicking the "New Event" button. It shows up, so I ran a SOQL query- basically *Select all fields from event*, and compared the data between events that do show as open, and the events I created that don't show up. I don't see any differences, unless I am just missing something.

Here's the code from my trigger:

```
    trigger CreateSFEventFromOperationsEvent on Operations_Events__c (after insert) {
    //When a new OperationsEvent is created, create an actual Salesforce Event under Account Activities.

    for (Operations_Events__c opEvent : Trigger.new) {
        Event event = new Event(
            OwnerId = opEvent.CreatedById,
            WhatId = opEvent.Event_Account__c,
            StartDateTime = opEvent.StartDate__c,
            EndDateTime = opEvent.End_Date__c,
            Subject = 'Go Live',
            Department_s_del__c = opEvent.Department__c,
            Product_s__c = opEvent.Product_s__c

        );
        insert event ;             
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the event is not coming up in the Open Activities is because the `activityDateTime` [field](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) in the Event will be set to the createdDate, unless you explicitly set it. This will cause the Event to appear in the `Activity history` Related List. To resolve this issue you have to set the ActivityDateTime field to the event start date while creating the event. So your code should look something like this:

```
Event event = new Event(
        OwnerId = opEvent.CreatedById,
        WhatId = opEvent.Event_Account__c,
        StartDateTime = opEvent.StartDate__c,
        EndDateTime = opEvent.End_Date__c,
        ActivityDateTime = opEvent.StartDate__c, //add this line
        Subject = 'Go Live',
        Department_s_del__c = opEvent.Department__c,
        Product_s__c = opEvent.Product_s__c

    );
```

Also please make sure that you have bulkified your trigger.

Comment: I love StackExchange. Answered and fixed in less than an hour. For other noobs out there like me, here's a good explanation of bulkifying triggers: http://rainforce.walkme.com/how-to-bulkify-trigger-in-salesforce/#.Upy4D-JFPSc